# Get value output from SQL Server stored procedure into variable

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

This seems to be a simple question but nevertheless I haven't found an answer yet.

I have the following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AllocateId]
AS
  BEGIN TRANSACTION

  UPDATE TOP(1) IdReservation 
  SET IsAllocated = 1
  OUTPUT DELETED.Id
  WHERE IsAllocated = 0 

  COMMIT TRANSACTION
  GO
```

It's been used in C# + EF code without a problem via `ExecuteFunction` of ObjectContext

```
ObjectResult<int> objectResult = ExecuteFunction<int>("AllocateId");
```

However when I try to call it directly from SQL script it doesn't seem to work

```
declare @Id int
EXEC @Id = [dbo].[AllocateId]
```

`@Id` is always 0. How do I get the value into @Id variable in sql script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Procedure return value is different from result set(s) returned by that procedure. Your stored procedure returns a result set and does not return a return value (which ends up being `null`, which gets converted to `0` implicitly upon exiting the procedure).
To get the resultset your existing procedure retuns, you need `insert ... exec`:

```
declare @t table (id int);

insert into @t
exec [dbo].[AllocateId];
```

If you want to return a value as a return value as well, you should amend you stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AllocateId]
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION

declare @id int;

UPDATE TOP(1) IdReservation
    SET @id = Id, IsAllocated = 1
    OUTPUT DELETED.Id
    WHERE IsAllocated = 0 

COMMIT TRANSACTION

return @id;
```

Then it will work in the way you describe in the question.

Comment: I noticed after I commented.  It's not clear though, except for your comment which makes it much more clear :)