# Why doesn't the tsql variable hold its value when called a second time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If you run the exec stored procedure command in SSMS, it produces this script:

```
USE [MY_DB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usr_DailyReportsEmpty]
        @username = N'someuser'

SELECT  'Return value' = @return_value

GO
```

However when I run the script the EXEC returns 16 and the SELECT returns 0. Why is that?

Comment: Put the code of the stored procedure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get value output from SQL Server stored procedure into variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618978/get-value-output-from-sql-server-stored-procedure-into-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the procedure to explicitly RETURN the value you wish to capture.  As Barry Kaye mentioned above when you simply select a value to return a result set the procedure returns 0 for success but if you use the RETURN statement the procedure will return that value.

In the following example, 1 will be selected as a result set when the first procedure is executed but the value captured in @return1 will be 0 for success.  The second procedure will not have a result set and the value captured in @return2 will be 3.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test1
AS
    SELECT 1;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Test2
AS
    RETURN 3;
GO

DECLARE @return1 INT, @return2 INT;
EXEC @return1 = Test1;
EXEC @return2 = Test2;
```

Comment: You and Barry are correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server when you `EXEC` a stored procedure the RETURN_VALUE typically indicates success or failure. 0 (zero) usually means success. It is not the same thing as the result of a `SELECT` statement. So your SP may `SELECT` 5 but you will still receive a `RETURN_VALUE` of 0 indicating the SP executed without errors.

Comment: Ah. So the fact that the last statement in my SP is SELECT @var is why it shows the number I'm expecting, but in actuality it doesn't return that number. It just returns 0 for success. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use output variables especially if waht you want to return is not an integer.